# rxDart not calling onError

Tags: flutter, stream, rxdart

I am trying to make a simple request to backend using rxDart. But the problem I face is that when I get a http error such as 404, onError is not called, however, it is possible to extract it in onData.

I have a little experience with RxJava + retrofit and there it works as expected, when there is a response with error http status code onError is called and can be handled appropriately.

**1. What am I doing wrong, or is it intended behavior?.**

```
  Object sendProfileData() {
    Stream<Response> stream = onboardingRepository.createUser(User(name: 'name', surname: 'surname', lat: 1.0, lng: 2.0));
    stream.listen((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      setAttributes();
    }, onError: (e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

**OnboardingRepository.dart:**

```
class OnboardingRepository {
  Observable<Response> createUser(User user) {
    return Observable.fromFuture(TMApi.createUser(user));
  }
}
```

**TMApi.dart:**

```
class TMApi {
  static Future<http.Response> createUser(User user) async {
    String url = '$baseUrl/create_user';
    return await http.post(url, body: json.encode(user.toJson()));
  }
}
```

2. What would be the best way to handle the event in the View? There should be an error displayed if error occurs, otherwise it should open a new screen. sendProfileData() method will return an Object, based on that I am going to perform actions in the view, but that doesn't sound like a very elegant solution...
3. Any suggestions on architecture are welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the http library in dart works a bit different than Retrofit.

The `Future` returned by `http.post` only throws an exception when there is an io error (socket error, no internet).

Server responses like 404 are reflected in the `http.Response`.

I created a simple convenience method that might help you:

```
void throwIfNoSuccess(http.Response response) {
  if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
    print('http error!');
    print(response.body);
    throw new HttpException(response);
  }
}

class HttpException implements Exception {
  HttpException(this.response);

  http.Response response;
}
```

How to use:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<UserProfile> getUserProfile(String userId) async {
  final url = 'https://example.com/api/users/$userId';

  final response = await http.get(url);

  throwIfNoSuccess(response);

  final jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);

  return UserProfile.fromJson(jsonBody);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where I'll put it?
Could you please explain a little?

Comment: added usage example ;)